# How to check a Keras backend function works correctly?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, backend

I have written a Keras backend function:

```
def myfunc(x):
   from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
   for ii in range(5):
       y = y + K.sin(2 * np.pi * ii * x)
   return x + 2
```

**Question 1:** How can give input and see the output? If it was a numpy array, I could do that easily.

**Question 2:** I want to use it as a custom activation function for my neural network. If I put

```
Print(y)
```

in the for loop, it does not print values during the training. How can I fix this?

Comment: Please check your `floorn()` function. It has syntax errors.